# Vim delete around tag for all script elements?

Tags: vim

I am interested to delete around the tag `dat` for all the the `<script>` elements in my html file.

How do I tell vim to apply `dat` for all `<script>` in my document?

Comment: Could your post a sample of your text? What does it look like now, and what do you want it to look like afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `dat`, you will need to search your buffer for `<script>` tags and do `dat` on each match:

```
/<script<CR>
dat
n.
n.
n.
```

Comment: I think multiple tags with same name can exist. So, you can rewrite your answer as a macro! :)